# Passing an object through a constructor?

Tags: c++

This is a homework problem. I am trying to pass an object through a constructor to create a new object with double the values. The object is an int array with upper and lower indices and a size. I'm not sure if I just change the values of the private variables to `* 2` or if I'm missing something completely.

Here's my class header:

```
const int SIZE = 100;

class intArray{
private:
    int iArray[SIZE];
    int arrLower, arrUpper;
    int size;

public:
    intArray();
    intArray(int size);
    intArray(int lower, int upper);
    intArray(intArray& input);
    int high();
    int low();
    int& operator[] (int size)             {  return iArray[size];  }

};
```

and all I have for the constructor so far:

```
intArray::intArray(intArray& input){

    input.iArray[size] *= 2;
    input.size *= 2;
    input.arrUpper *= 2;
    input.arrLower *= 2;

}
```

which I am not even sure is correct.

Comment: that is not a member function that is a constructor!

Comment: @BWG True, edited for phrasing.

Comment: Nope, looks like you're changing the original.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
intArray::intArray(intArray& input){

    input.iArray[size] *= 2;
    input.size *= 2;
    input.arrUpper *= 2;
    input.arrLower *= 2;

}
```

This is incorrect.

Since you prefix everything with `input.`, you are modifying the original which is not what you want. Just copy all the old values, but multiplied by two

```
intArray::intArray(intArray& input){

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        iArray[i] = input.iArray[i] * 2; //set this array to 2x the input array
    }
    size = input.size * 2;
    arrUpper = input.arrUpper * 2;
    arrLower = input.arrLower * 2;

}
```

While this will sort of work, the array is the same size, but `size` is multiplied by two, which is just wrong. I'm not sure exactly what your class is actually supposed to be doing, but I can tell you it doesn't really make sense. What are `arrUpper`, and `arrLower`? If you answer, I can help you some more.

Here is one that makes a little more sense, but I still don't know what some of your variables mean.

```
intArray::intArray(intArray& input){
    size = input.size; //keep this the same
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        iArray[i] = input.iArray[i] * 2; //set this array to 2x the input array
    }
    arrUpper = input.arrUpper; //what is this even?
    arrLower = input.arrLower;

}
```

Comment: if you want to keep the size of the new array equal to the old one. You should do 'input.size = size' from the beginning of the for loop. After that, you can loop from 0 to the new size.

Comment: @HoangMinh Ooh, good catch! And I think you mean `size = input.size`, not the inverse.

Comment: `input` is a new object and its size is undefined when you created it. So you cannot assign its size to the variable `size` of the old object. Instead, you want to put the old value of size into the new one. Therefore, it must be `input.size = size`

Comment: Sorry for the lack of info on the code. I am practicing overloading operators so some of these variables are for the other constructors. `arrUpper` is the upper index and `arrLower` is the lower index (i.e `intArray z(3,4)` where 3 would be the start of the array and 4 would be the end.

Comment: @HoangMinh Actually I think you're wrong. Input is not new, it is a parameter. It is impossible for it to be new.

Comment: @Ryan Oh, I see. My final example is wrong in that case, but now that you see how to do it you can judge yourself what can be done.

Comment: @Ryan One last thing, you may want to make it a `const intArray&`, because you don't modify the original at all. Jamal mentions this in his answer too.

Answer (score 2):

If you must keep the passed object intact, then pass it by `const&`.  You should then modify the data members of the *current* object, *not* the parameter (and if you try it anyway, you'll receive errors).

```
intArray::intArray(intArray const& input) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        iArray[i] = 2 * input.iArray[i];
    }

    size = 2 * input.size;
    arrUpper = 2 * input.arrUpper;
    input.arrLower = 2 * input.arrLower;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have your copy constructor already defined (intArray::intArray(intArray&)). What you want to do in this is to perform a deep copy in your copy constructor of the array elements.

```
intArray::intArray(intArray& input)
{

    for(int i=input.low(); i<=input.hig(); ++i)
    {
        iArray[i] = input.iArray[i]*2;
    }
}
```